# Compiler instantiates the function in a template class even without invoking it

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, instantiation

I had a wrong perception that `template` function in a `class` is instantiated only if it's invoked. See the below simple code:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
  T *p; 
  T& operator * () { return *p; }
};

int main ()
{
  A<int> ai;   // ok
  int i = *ai;  // works fine
  A<void> av;  // compiler complains even "*av" is not called
}
```

Just while declaring `A<void>`, compiler errors out as:

```
error: forming reference to void
```

I tried to specialize the function for `void` outside the template as below:

```
template<>
void A<void>::operator * () {}
```

But it doesn't help and gives error as:

```
error: no member function ‘operator*’ declared in ‘A<void>’
```

Is there any way to fix this with C++03 ?

Comment: Yeah well, you ARE invoking the template. Plus, the way you invoke it, you're even creating a variable so there's calls to constructors and destructors, which is even more "invoking" than just mentioning the type.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Christian: Member functions of class templates are not instantiated unless used.

Comment: @KirilKirov, that will be too much to explain as the actual code is complex. So I just demonstrated only working example. In brief, I can say that I have created a smart pointer `A`, which should be convertible from any type to `A<void>` and there are subsequent requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
template < typename T >
struct ReferenceOrVoid
{ typedef T& Value; };

template < >
struct ReferenceOrVoid < void >
{ typedef void Value; };

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T *p; 
    typename ReferenceOrVoid < T > :: Value
    operator * () { return *p; }
};
```

Of course it depends what you want `A` to behave in case `T` is `void`. You can also specialise the whole `A` struct for `void`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is sufficient if you give the function a different return type for `void`:

```
template <typename T>
struct is _void {
    enum { value = false };
};
template <>
struct is_void<> {
    enum { value = true };
};

struct A {
    ...
    typename enable_if<!is_void<T::value>, T&>::type
    operator*() {
        ...
    }
};
```

Since the signature may still be checked you may need to use a conditional type, e.g., making it `void` when instantiated with `void`:

```
template <bool, typename T1, typename>
struct conditional {
    typedef T1 type;
};
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct conditional<false, T1, T2> {
    typedef T2 type;
};
```

Comment: Just from the glimps of your answer, I figured out that I need to make return type changeable, and I came up with the solution which is exactly matching as @DyP's answer. Still +1 to this.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of the function will be instantiated, the body of the function will not. `T` is substituted in the whole class definition, no matter if you're using the function or not. Note that this:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
  T *p; 
  T *operator * () { return p->aklsdjlkasjd(); }
};

int main ()
{
  A<void> av;  
}
```

Will compile since you're not using `operator*`.

Comment: Additionally the attempt at providing an explicit specialization for `A<void>::operator*` fails because it doesn't match the declaration in the primary template: the return types are different. (Which is the intent of the OP of course, but is not allowed.)