# Forming reference to void

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that should allow `void` as a template parameter. This class does have a function that passes a reference of the parameter, so I did the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct trait
{
    typedef typename boost::conditional<
        boost::is_void<T>::value,
        void, T &
    >::type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    typename trait<T>::type ref()
    {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Yet the compiler claims I would form a reference to `void` in instantiation of `struct trait<void>`. Why so and how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiler instantiates the function in a template class even without invoking it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762432/compiler-instantiates-the-function-in-a-template-class-even-without-invoking-it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you clearly form a reference to `void` in your conditional type definition when you say `T&`. This seems to be best dealt with a specialization:

```
template <typename T> struct trait { typedef T& type; };
template <> struct trait<void> { typedef void type; };
```

Comment: You can also make it easy on yourself by going with the standard `std::add_lvalue_reference`, which just works for `void`.

Comment: ...and `const void` and `volatile void` and so on. It's a good idea. :)